# How to update homebrew in preparation for installing node/npm on macOS Mojave

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew, chown

I attempted to install node.js/npm onto a macbook running `Mojave 10.14.5` so that I can do local development of a web app.  From internet research my understanding is the first step is updating homebrew in preparation for installation but I got the error `"Error: /usr/local must be writable!"` when I ran:

```
brew update
```

I searched the internet and other people appeared to have the command below fix the problem, but for me that didn't work and I still got the error.

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

Can anyone offer any advice as to what I can do so that I can update brew and install node.js/npm?  Is the brew update required or should I just skip that step?

Below is the output from `brew --prefix` that may help...

```
MacBook-Pro:usr dannyboy$ ls -l $(brew --prefix)
total 215896
-rw-r--r--   1 dannyboy  admin       3161 May 23  2016 CODEOFCONDUCT.md
drwxr-xr-x   5 dannyboy  admin        160 Nov  4  2018 Cellar
-rw-r--r--   1 dannyboy  admin       1241 Jan 13  2016 LICENSE.txt
drwxr-xr-x  11 dannyboy  admin        352 Nov  4  2018 Library
-rw-r--r--   1 dannyboy  admin       3918 May 23  2016 README.md
drwxrwxr-x  33 dannyboy  admin       1056 Nov  4  2018 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 dannyboy  admin         96 Nov  4  2018 etc
lrwxr-xr-x   1 dannyboy  admin         27 May 22  2016 hadoop -> /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2-src
drwxr-xr-x@ 22 dannyboy  staff        704 Nov  4  2018 hadoop-2.7.2-src
-rw-r--r--@  1 dannyboy  staff  110520320 May 22  2016 hadoop-2.7.2-src.tar
drwxrwxr-x  30 dannyboy  admin        960 Nov  4  2018 include
drwxrwxr-x  23 dannyboy  admin        736 Nov  4  2018 lib
drwxr-xr-x   5 dannyboy  wheel        160 Nov  4  2018 man
lrwxr-xr-x   1 dannyboy  wheel         27 Jan 18  2014 mysql -> mysql-5.6.15-osx10.7-x86_64
drwxr-xr-x  18 dannyboy  wheel        576 Nov  4  2018 mysql-5.6.15-osx10.7-x86_64
-rw-r--r--   1 dannyboy  owner       1536 Jan 18  2014 mysql_db_backup_20140118.libertyrocks.tar
drwxr-xr-x   5 dannyboy  admin        160 Nov  4  2018 opt
drwxr-xr-x   3 dannyboy  wheel         96 Nov  4  2018 remotedesktop
drwxrwxr-x   9 dannyboy  admin        288 Nov  4  2018 share
```

Also requested...

```
MacBook-Pro:usr dannyboy$ ls -l /usr
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  971 root  wheel  31072 May 15 01:37 bin
drwxr-xr-x  307 root  wheel   9824 May 15 01:37 lib
drwxr-xr-x  250 root  wheel   8000 May 15 01:37 libexec
drwxr-xr-x   27 root  wheel    864 Nov  4  2018 local
drwxr-xr-x  239 root  wheel   7648 May 15 01:37 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   46 root  wheel   1472 Nov  4  2018 share
drwxr-xr-x    5 root  wheel    160 Sep 21  2018 standalone
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the output of: `whoami` and `ls -l $(brew --prefix)` ?

Comment: I added it to the main question in case the information is globally useful.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Show also `ls -l /usr`

Comment: I added the ls -l to the main question. Thanks for taking a look.